# Android, automatically connecting to wifi networks that have no internet access

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm calling the function [WifiManager.addNetwork(WifiConfiguration)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)) to try and add an adhoc wifi network to the device's wifi configurations.  But on Android M this function returns -1, I'm assuming because it doesn't have internet access.  It works fine on most other devices.  Below is code snippet I'm using.

`WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfiguration.SSID = '\"' + ssid + '\"';
        wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = false;
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);`

Any way to get around the internet connectivity check and force the network to be added?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the network after that :

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
         wifiManager.disconnect();
         wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
         wifiManager.reconnect();               
    enter code here
         break;
    }           
 }
```